# Selenium XPath isn’t working: Unable to locate element error

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, click, anchor

I'm trying to make a Instagram bot that logs in, opens your profile etc. Everything works fine until one anchor tag:

`self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/ul/li[3]/a").click()`

I also tried the shorter way of writing this:

`self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/Obserwowani:')]").click()`

and also tried searching by id.

This is a snippet of my function:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/section/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a").click()
sleep(15)
self.driver.find_element_by_id("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/ul/li[3]/a").click()#not working
sleep(4)
scrollbox = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]"
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong please? Even sleep() doesn't work.

Comment: This is the error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: it doesnt work on any element on the page

Comment: OK, but where is html?

Comment: Add html or at least a link to the site

Comment: Xpath isnt working == your xpath are bad !!